# WatchKit title disappears if modal view shown on paged modal views

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, xcode-6.2

This issue is quite simple to reproduce. And I think this may be a bug in watchKit.

If I display View with:

```
[self presentControllerWithName:@"OneButtonView" context:nil];
```

It works great.
If I use this view for one button, and open exact same view with that button, new modal view comes on top of original (as expected). If I click title - top most view gets closed and I see parent view. In this way I can create 10 pages and go back one by one to the very first one. Everything is great.

Issue exists only if you try presenting one/more modal views by using this method:

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"OneButtonView"] contexts:nil];
```

If I do that, new view is presented on top (as expected), I can close it by pressing the title (as expected) but title/titles for all pages that were created with `presentControllerWithNames:` disappear as soon as you come back from child modal view. This behaves identical for one or multiple views presented this way.

I tried setting title explicitly for one/all views presented this way but it didn't help.

Anyone encountered this or have any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, this is a known bug. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311026/apple-watch-status-bar-not-visible-after-presenting-a-modal-screen-from-page-ba

Comment: Yes i see, i guess my post is duplicate then... Though i did google/searched for it quite a lot.