# WKInterfaceMenu sets model InterfaceController as root InterfaceController

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller, wkinterfacemenu

When bringing up a menu from a modal `WKInterfaceController` presented from the `rootController` via `presentControllerWithName:context:`, the modal controller becomes the root controller:

[image]  <— Modal (see `Cancel`)

[image]  <— Menu

[image]  <— Root? (no `Cancel`)

Is this a WatchKit bug, or are modal controllers not meant to have menus?

### "Solution"

Since this is a known bug, my temporary workaround was just to add a `Cancel` button to the modal controller and use `reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:` to present them as root. The `Cancel` button reloads the root controller to my initial root controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug that is present in WatchKit/iOS 8.2 and 8.3. The issue occurs when you present a modal interface that then presents another modal interface on top (like the Force Touch menu).

You can find a (nasty) workaround here: [Apple Watch: Status bar not visible after presenting a modal screen from page based navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311026/apple-watch-status-bar-not-visible-after-presenting-a-modal-screen-from-page-ba/29361241#29361241)

Comment: Might very well just forgo modal presentation entirely, and provide my own `Cancel` button right from the start.

Comment: Most of the developers I've talked to have decided to simply add their own `Cancel` button for now. It's strange to have two identical buttons, but it's one of the only reasonable workarounds at the moment.