# reloadRootControllersWithNames hides title and status bar, watchkit

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, watchkit

When trying to user `reloadRootControllersWithNames`, after my views all load their titles disappear along with the rest of the statusbar.

Is there something that specifies showing and hiding the status bar and title in `Watchkit`?

**Code:**

```
[WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[ @"SystolicEntryController", @"DiastolicEntryController" ] contexts:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, there is currently no WatchKit method to hide or show the status bar and its title.

The experience you're describing sounds similar to this bug (which was fixed in Watch OS 1.0.1): [Apple Watch: Status bar not visible after presenting a modal screen from page based navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311026/apple-watch-status-bar-not-visible-after-presenting-a-modal-screen-from-page-ba)